# OpenSolaris changing primary user group

Tags: opensolaris

How to change primary user group of a user? Preferably without losing the current primary group altogether as the user is part of 'staff' ie. admin. I suppose I could create another admin user and then recreate the original user, but is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 4):

Use [usermod(1M)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1462/usermod-1m.html#scrolltoc):

```
# usermod -g PRIMARY_GROUP -G SECONDARY_GROUP username
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [newgrp](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1461/newgrp-1.html#scrolltoc) command?

Comment: newgrp changes the group for just the current login session, usermod as suggested by @gtirloni changes the default groups defined in the passwd and group files for all future logins.